# How to send multiple Images in a response?

Tags: javascript, express, response

I'm trying to get a list of all of my uploaded images (array of images) from a db using express. However, when I make a request to get them, I get a weird square, or I get a lot of weird characters.

I've tried streaming the array as a whole, I've tried sending it using res.end/res.write one by one by looping through the array, I've tried streaming and piping, but so far, nothing.

```
//gets data from db
let getAllPhotos = await ListingPhoto.find({
    "listing._id": listingId
  }).then((images) => {
    return images.map(item => {
      //want to send response here as we go 
      return item.file;
    })
  })

//or send all the files(images) that's in getAllphotos down here
```

I want to be able to see all of the photos in the response

Comment: Why do you need the function `map`?

Comment: Perhaps you are receiving a byte array buffer ```(Buffer.isBuffer(body))```, then you can convert it to what you need ```body.toString('base64')```

Comment: Ele, I need a map to loop through the list of files that one ListingPhoto collection might have. Then I'm returning each file from the Image document  (that's inside the collection) since it holds other data.